# Matter.js change object properties onClick

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I create rectangle

```
var options = { 
    isStatic: true,
    angle: Math.PI * 0.15
}
elastic = Bodies.rectangle(300, 245, 75, 75, options),
```

add this to scene

```
World.add(_world, [elastic]);
```

and i want change this obj options onClick.

```
   Events.on(_engine, 'tick', function(event) {
        if(_mouseConstraint.mouse.button == 0){
                var options2 = { 
                    isStatic: false,
                    angle: Math.PI * 0.35,
                    friction: 0.0001
                elastic2 = Bodies.rectangle(300, 245, 75, 75, options2);
                World.add(_engine.world, elastic2);
            }
        }
    });
```

thats my try, how to set new properties on object without creating new with new option?

Answer (score 2):

Solution my object jump :)

```
var rect = Bodies.rectangle(300, 300, 40, 40, {id: "jumper", isStatic: false, friction: 0.001 });
    World.add(_world, rect);
    var jumper = Composite.get(_world, "jumper", "body");
    _sceneEvents.push(

        Events.on(_engine, 'mousedown', function(event) {
            var mousePosition = event.mouse.position;
            jumper.force = {
                x: 0.001,
                y: -0.01
            };

            console.log('mousedown at ' + mousePosition.x + ' ' + mousePosition.y);
        })

    );
```

Comment: I believe mousedown events have moved to mouseConstraint, like: `Events.on(MouseConstraint, "mousedown", callback)`. See docs: https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/MouseConstraint.html#events